# How to check if I have gcc installed on a Mac using terminal

Tags: c, terminal

I have tried using `gcc --version` but it shows:

> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

I have the new M1 MacBook and I'm using the `zsh` terminal. Does this message mean I don't have it installed or is the command not working?

How else do I check if I have `gcc` installed and what ways are there to install it other than installing Xcode?

Comment: Well you definitely don't have it installed. Run `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: Installing Xcode actually gives you *clang*, not gcc. But Apple for some annoying reason has gcc set up as an alias to it.

Comment: Ah yeah, good point. "some annoying reason has gcc set up as an alias to it." It's pretty convenient tbh, and I'd suspect it's sufficient for most people who just need to compile a small file here and there. And for those for whom it doesn't work, they're probably the kind of people who would know how to install `gcc` for themselves and remove the alias